# how to insert images links and put images in storage without replacing images using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a data to insert, all the data to insert with success, except image, I insert the image in `public\storage\annonces\August2020` and link in database with the name annonces.jpg but when I want to insert the 2nd image it finds the 1st by the same name then he replaces 1st by the 2nd,i find alwys in my folder last image.

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $Annonce = new Annonce($request->all());
       $jdate = Carbon::now();
       if($request->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $image->storeAs("public\annonces\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year,'annonces'.".".$image->extension());
        $Annonce->image = "annonces\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year."\annonces" .".".$image->extension(); 
        }
        $Annonce->save();
        return Redirect::to("/")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign unique name to the file to avoid overriding for example concatenate the name of file with  date along with full time including hours, mins and seconds to make it unique.
For example

```
 $jdate = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s');// 2009-10-16 21:30:45
// concatenate date with time to file name


 $image->storeAs("public\annonces\\".$jdate,'annonces'.".".$image->extension());
```